# Creating Dynamic Forms in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on a project that involves a form with some standard fields and some custom field users define later. The standard forms are defined on a model in models.py. For example:

```
class Order(models.model):
    number = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

I then use this model to create a simple model form to make a way to fill in the information. That's pretty standard Django.

The tricky thing is that my users want to be able to add arbitrary fields to the form. They would like to be able to use the Admin interface to basically modify the form and add values to it at run time.

So, they might want a new text field called "Tracking Number" or something like that. The trick is that they only need it sometimes and they want to be able to add it dynamically without rebuilding the whole database.

I can create a fairly simple model to represent the custom fields like so:

```
class CustomField(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(choices=FIELD_TYPES)
    required = models.BooleanField()
```

I think I can then take the ModelForm for the Order class and extend it to add these custom fields. What I am unsure of is how to link the custom field values back to the Order.

I know this all might sound odd, but in practice it makes sense. Each user has slightly different needs for the form and want to tweak it. If I have to hard code the models to have their specific fields, then I will have to have a fork for each user. That simply doesn't scale. If instead they can simply add the fields through the admin interface, then things are much simpler.

I feel like this is something that is perhaps already solved by someone out there. I simply cannot find a solution. I can't be the only one who has gotten this kind of request right?